# Using Geocoder to find a non-address point, return individual components, then append to current dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding

I am currently working on a project that looks at how standardized testing ranges across boroughs in New York City. I have a dataset that provides a district borough number (DBN) but does not give an address. When I search the DBN on google, it does provides the exact address of each high school.

I am new to pandas so please bear with me. I tried to have geocoder run through the column of district borough numbers and then have the output appended to the current data frame.

---

```
import pandas as pd  
import geocoder
from googlegeocoder import GoogleGeocoder
```

---

```
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linnaha/NYCdata/master/sat_2014.csv"
            satdata = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='latin-1')
            satdata.head()
```

[image of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rexs.png)

---

```
geocoder = GoogleGeocoder()
list_of_dbn = satdata['DBN']


for address in list_of_dbn:
    try:
        search = geocoder.get(address)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    first_result = search[0]
    output =first_result.formatted_address
    print(output)
    satdata["zip_code"]= output
```

---

It goes through the list and returns addresses

---

```
220 Henry St, New York, NY 10002, USA
200 Monroe St, New York, NY 10002, USA
420 E 12th St, New York, NY 10009, USA
198 Forsyth St, New York, NY 10002, USA
145 Stanton St, New York, NY 10002, USA
145 Stanton St, New York, NY 10002, USA
111 Columbia St, New York, NY 10002, USA
198 Forsyth St, New York, NY 10002, USA
525 E Houston St, New York, NY 10002, USA
225 E 23rd St, New York, NY 10010, USA
525 W 50th St, New York, NY 10019, USA
350 Grand St, New York, NY 10002, USA
```

---

But when I look at the dataset again, it only repeats the same address for all rows. 
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuvJc.png)

---

Lastly, if it were to work, how would I be able split the string to only have the zip code and city? This is what I've tried. I've also tried using Nominatim but it does not recognize the DBN.

---

```
new_list = []
for var in satdata.zip_code:
    new_list.append(var.rsplit(maxsplit = 1)[0].replace(" ","_"))
satdata.zip_code = new_list
```

---

```
145_Stanton_St,_New_York,_NY_10002,
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At every iteration of your for loop you are overwriting the entire `"zip_code"` with `output`

```
satdata["zip_code"]= output
```

so the output with same value in all row is easily explained.
You could initialize:

```
satdata["zip_code"]=''
```

and then do

```
satdata.loc[satdata['DBN']==adress,"zip_code"]= output
```

in the for loop.
Let me know if that works

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I'm new to this. Thank you so much.